# Finding all continuously differentiable functions satisfying an equation

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find all continuously differentiable functions $f : \mathbb{C}  \to \mathbb{C}  $ satisfying the equation :

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = z $ on $ \mathbb{C}$.

The left hand side is the standard partial differential operator for complex functions:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}  = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} )$

I'm stuck because surely if $f$ is continuously differentiable it satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations and since the CR equations imply that:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = 0 \implies  z = 0 $.

And so there are no such continuously differentiable functions ?

I know this is incorrect but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is *not* incorrect. If $f$ is differentiable and its domain is an open subset of $\mathbb C$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline z}$ is $0$ everywhere.

Comment: So what functions are solutions to this equation?

Comment: @somjo There aren't any.